# Store user input on selected day on month calendar

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, monthcalendar

I have created a form that accepts user input for a couple different pieces of info (title, location , date(from a monthCalendar) etc..), when the Add button is clicked the information is stored in the current array element and the Title is displayed in a listBox. When the Title in the listBox is selected the rest of the information for that specific Title is re-populated in the appropriate textBox.

I have been trying to take this a step further with no success. When the Add button is clicked I would like to have the user input saved to the date selected on the monthCalendar. So if the user clicks on a date that has no information saved, the listBox remains empty. If there has been information saved on a date, the listBox would then display the Title(s).

Code snippets:

```
class MeetingManager
{
    private Meeting[] meetings; 
    public int currentIndex;  
    public int maxIndex;   
    private string title;       
    private string location;  
    private string startTime; 
    private string endTime; 
    private string notes;    

    public MeetingManager()
    {
        meetings = new Meeting[10];
        currentIndex = -1;
        maxIndex = -1;
    }

   // excluded getter/setters + basic error checking 

    public void Add()
    {
        try
        {
            if (maxIndex >= meetings.Length - 1)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("YOU CAN ONLY CREATE 10 MEETINGS");
            }
            else
            {
                maxIndex++;
                currentIndex = maxIndex;
                Meeting temp = new Meeting(Title, Location, StartTime, EndTime, Notes);
                meetings[maxIndex] = temp;
                Title = meetings[maxIndex].Title;
                Location = meetings[maxIndex].Location;
                StartTime = meetings[maxIndex].StartTime;
                EndTime = meetings[maxIndex].EndTime;
                Notes = meetings[maxIndex].Notes;

            }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw ex; // toss it up to the presentation

        }
    }

    public void Add(string title, string location, string startTime, string endTime, string notes)
    {
        try
        {
            Title = title;
            Location = location;
            StartTime = startTime;
            EndTime = endTime;
            Notes = notes;
            Add();
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
     public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
```

}

```
     public partial class CalendarForm : Form
{
     private MeetingManager mManager; // reference to business layer object

     private void calendarSaveChangesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            mManager.Title = textBoxTitle.Text;
            mManager.Location = textBoxLocation.Text;
            mManager.StartTime = maskedStartTimeTextBox.Text;
            mManager.EndTime = maskedEndTimeTextBox.Text;
            mManager.Notes = notesTextBox.Text;
            mManager.Add();

            meetingListBox.Enabled = true;
            meetingListBox.Items.Add(mManager);

            //clears the textBoxes after clickng saveChanges
            textBoxTitle.Text = "";
            textBoxLocation.Text = "";
            maskedStartTimeTextBox.Text = "";
            maskedEndTimeTextBox.Text = "";
            notesTextBox.Text = "";


        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message);
        }

    }

        /// <summary>
    ///  When a meeting is selected from the listBox, it re-populates
    /// the empty fields with the information stored in the array element
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void meetingListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MeetingManager m = meetingListBox.SelectedItem as MeetingManager;
        if (m != null)
        {
            textBoxTitle.Text = m.Title;
            textBoxLocation.Text = m.Location;
            maskedStartTimeTextBox.Text = m.StartTime;
            maskedEndTimeTextBox.Text = m.EndTime;
            notesTextBox.Text = m.Notes;

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Sounds a bit messy... Can you show us some code?

Comment: ...and what exactly are asking for?

Comment: @HaunsTM some coding has been added..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you could try something like this:

```
class MeetingManager
{
    ...


    //add and implement a find method which returns a Meeting-object if there is a
 //corresponding meeting date (in private Meeting[] meetings;)

    public Meeting MeetingFinder(DateTime meetingTime)
    {
        //if there is a corresponding meeting-object for the date, return the meeting object
        //if there isn't, return null
    }

    ...
}
```

---

```
public partial class CalendarForm : Form
{

    ...

    private void monthCalendar_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        //which date was selected?
            var selectedDate = monthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start;


        //do we have that date in the meetings?
        var meetingOnTheSelectedDate = mManager.MeetingFinder(selectedDate);

        if(meetingOnTheSelectedDate != null)
        {
            //populate your winform with the data from meetingOnTheSelectedDate
        }
    }

    ...

}
```